# Self-referencing tuple in python

Tags: python, programming-puzzle

Goal: create a self-referencing tuple satisfying `x == (x,)` in any version of Python. Standard libraries, matplotlib, numpy, pandas only.

Answers meeting this extra condition are prioritised (which may be impossible): this tuple should also be insertable into a dict or set.

If the extra condition is impossible, apart from the low-hanging optimization of the below code, I am still interested in a qualitatively different approach of similar length or better.

---

I had previously assumed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61280229/5805389) to be one of the shortest, but as @mousetail brought up, actually it crashes python when inserted into a dict or set.

```py
import ctypes
tup = (0,)
ctypes.c_longlong.from_address(id(tup)+24).value = id(tup)
```

I notice this also happens with the other answer in that post, so I'm wondering if there's a way to resolve it (the ideal answer), or if that is inherent in python.

Comment: Trying to insert this tuple into a dict or set crashes the python interpreter

Comment: Edited to account for that; didn't know, thanks!

Comment: May `x` be anything we choose? Or must it be able to be _anything reasonable_?

Comment: The linked question asks for `x is (x,)` rather than `x == (x,)`.

Comment: I assume you don't want the loophole where `x` is an object for which `__eq__` is defined so that it equals anything?

Comment: Yes, although I am not fully aware of all loopholes to specify against for all of those

Comment: Why such probably doesn't exist: I think the problem lies with `tuple.__hash__` which somewhat expectedly doesn't take kindly to the unbounded recursive structure. If you subclass `tuple` and reimplement `__hash__` it looks like you can make it work: [proof of concept](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY9LCsIwEIb3OUWWCdZSxYUUegcXuhIJpZnYQkxDHkIRT-KmG72TR_AWJn0IDswwfMz8M__jpTtXt6rvn96J5fb9aS66NQ5XrtNgUSVLa_H-sCPOawk0RzgEB4EZq0tbM0YsSDHxEI3AERRFrMfslBtw3ii8mgdAWpjhoJn-KyEUKC6GmyRLKEXjK2nFZKvOMVNh2gsrOTdgLWl4_I0u1huaXkvpISxPDGnTKEduoc9DJj_NPLvT0fDke_b_BQ). Not very golfy, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 48 bytes

```python
from marshal import*
t=loads(b'\xa9\1r\0\0\0\0')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chN7GoOCMxRyEztyC/qESLq8Q2Jz8xpVgjST2mItEyxrAoxgAC1TX/FxRl5pVolOgolEQbxCpkFiuAmAq2tgpAMU3N/wA)

Not portable, depends on the interpreter. There's probably a similar (portable) `pickle` version, although it would need to be handcrafted since the `pickle.dumps` gives an error due to recursion depth.

Uses `marshal`, which is a standard library for serializing Python objects. The string is the string received by serializing the object produced by the code in the question.

Comment: You may want to add `, t == (t,)` to your print in the TIO-link, since that's what the question is asking for. It does seem to result in `True` though, but I'd prefer an explanation before I upvote it tbh.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76642214) SO answer has an explanation for an identical approach.